# changes don't seem to take affect in Postgres DB

Tags: python, psycopg2

Whenever I run my python scripts that interact with a postgresql database, they don't seem to have an effect.  I don't get any error, and everything in my code seems to execute fine (e.g., my prints after DB operations show up as expected), but when I look at the database later, I don't see any evidence the code ran.  For example, I have the following code:

```
def testDeleteWins():
    deleteWins()
    print "Old wins deleted."

def deleteWins():
    DB = connect()
    c = DB.cursor()
    c.execute("DELETE FROM wins;")
    print "Task Done!"

def connect()
    print"Connected"
    return psycopg2.connect("dbname=project")
```

if I run `testDeleteWins()` I see the "Task Done!" print out, but none of the records are actually removed from the `wins` table.  What do I need to do to get the changes to take effect in the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `psycopg2` has `cursor`'s that do not autocommit.  In `deleteWins` add `DB.commit()` after your `c.execute`.  `deleteWins` will then look like:

```
def deleteWins():
    DB = connect()
    c = DB.cursor()
    c.execute("DELETE FROM wins;")
    DB.commit()
    print "Task Done!"
```

Comment: Thanks, did not realize it needed commit, can you please modify your answer though? You're not supposed to commit from the cursor, but from the connection itself => DB.commit(). Maybe even just write the whole method with that at the end for others who need?